# How to get MusicSequenceSetUserCallback in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using MusicPlayer & MusicSequence for play .mid file. i want to get Audio duration from .mid file, set Playback Speed on .mid file. i am using below code for play .mid file

```
 var musicPlayer: MusicPlayer?
    var sequence: MusicSequence?


    func play(file: String) {

        guard let midiFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "mid") else {
            return
        }

        NewMusicPlayer(&musicPlayer)
        NewMusicSequence(&sequence)

        if let musicPlayer = musicPlayer, let sequence = sequence {

            MusicSequenceFileLoad(sequence, midiFile as CFURL, .midiType, MusicSequenceLoadFlags())
            MusicPlayerSetSequence(musicPlayer, sequence)
            MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer)

        }
    }
```